# How do I add a `ttk.Notebook` widget to a `tk.Frame`?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can create this GUI

```
┏━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━┓
┃ @ ┃ hello world                 ┃ X ┃
┣━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━┫
┃                                     ┃
┃                                     ┃
┃                                     ┃
┃                                     ┃   <- Frame 0
┃                                     ┃
┃                                     ┃
┃                                     ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃                OTHER                ┃   <- Frame 1
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

with the code shown below<sup>1</sup>.

However, I want to add a `ttk.Notebook` to the `Frame 0`.

```
┏━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━┓
┃ @ ┃ hello world                 ┃ X ┃
┣━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━┫
┃ ┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┓ ┃
┃ ┃ Tab 0 ┃ Tab 1 ┃ Tab ... ┃ Tab n ┃ ┃
┃ ┣━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┫ ┃
┃ ┃                                 ┃ ┃
┃ ┃                                 ┃ ┃   <- Frame 0 with n tabs (Notebooks)
┃ ┃                                 ┃ ┃
┃ ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛ ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃                OTHER                ┃   <- Frame 1
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Just adding the `ttk.Notebook` to the `tk.Frame` instance does not seem to work (i.e., `tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.frame0)`).
So, how do I add a `ttk.Notebook` widget to a `tk.Frame`?

---

<sup>1</sup> GUI code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("hello world")

        self.frame0 = tk.Frame(self, background="green")
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self, background="blue")

        self.frame0.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frame1.pack(side="top", fill=tk.X, expand=True)

        self.frame0_label0 = tk.Label(self.frame0, text=" ")
        self.frame0_label0.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.frame1_label0 = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="OTHER")
        self.frame1_label0.grid(row=0, column=0)


def main():
    MyApp().mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-notebook/) might help.

Comment: No, because, as I wrote in the question, just binding the `Notebook` to `self.frame0` instead of `self`, as one might think when reading this and other docs/tutorials, does **not** work.

Comment: @user69453: it _does_ work. If you think it doesn't, you're doing something wrong. Unfortunately your example doesn't show what you're doing wrong since it doesn't attempt to create a notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add it exactly like you add any other widget. Create the widget, add it to the window with `pack`, `grid`, or `place`, and then add tabs to it using the `add` method.

For example:

```
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.frame0)
tabControl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

tab1 = tk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = tk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
tabControl.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")
```

For more information, see the [official tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#notebook). Tkdocs.com also has [an example](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook)

Comment: Sorry for the spam comment, but I would really like to understand what I did wrong the 20 minutes before as this looks exactly like what I tried (as I wrote in the question)...anyways, many thanks!

Comment: @user69453 is it possible you had forgotten to add the `Notebook` to a geometry manager (i.e. `pack`, `grid`, or `place`) as Bryan mentioned up top? I'm just guessing since we can't see your implementation, but that would do it.